# How to open Genymotion Dev Menu on Ubuntu? (Ctrl + M doesn't work)

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I'm currently using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

I started my virtual device with the help of Genymotion, but as I used to open Dev Menu in Windows with Ctrl + M, doesn't trigger a thing. I need to open Dev Menu, but have no idea how to open it without this. I really appreciate any help I can get.

I've already tried Ctrl + M and

`adb shell input keyevent 82` didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance.